# JSOUP Does not work

Tags: java, android, web, android-studio, jsoup

I'm trying to get the title of a random Wikipedia articles and **view them at a listview**.


**http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random** this link returns a random wiki article 


Here is my code:

```
final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.container);
    String []vals = new String[4];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
    {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random").get() ;
            vals[i] = doc.title();
        }catch(IOException e){}
    }
    final ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<>() ;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < vals.length ; i++)
        List.add(vals[i]);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this , android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1 , List) ;
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But when I run my code at the emulator the app **crashs**, any idea??

Comment: i dont actually know , simply a crash!

Comment: can't you see any errors /logcat ?

Comment: `catch(IOException e){}` is so bad.why empty catch block ?

Comment: You need to run this in an AsyncTask, otherwise you get a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Comment: "JSOUP Does not work" -- yes it does as a rule of thumb. If it doesn't, you need proof that it doesn't and your code does not show such proof. The problem here is not that jsoup does not work but that you use it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making a network request from the UI thread which causes an exception

You need to do network transferes on a back ground thread.
Personally I use Androids AsyncTask class for this so to set the text in a textView to something off the internet you need do this

```
private class GetTextOverNetwork extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

     protected String doInBackGround()
    {
      // here you get the info off the internet 
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
     // here you update your UI
    }
}
```

add the above private class to you activity and modify and variable you need
Remember

1) you cant access the network from the main thread so you do in in this case in doInBackGround

2) you cant modify the UI from the Background thread so you do the modification in the onPostExcute method

3) Asynctask is of the form AsyncTask  so it doesn't have to be